# App crashes when I try to read QString from socket

Tags: qt, sockets

I am trying to develop a Qt program using sockets for client and server communication. I need help with figuring out why my server crashes when the client connects and the server tries to get a QString?

I have this code on the server side:

```
void Client::onReadyRead() {
    qDebug() << "On ready read!";
    QDataStream in(mSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    for (;;) {

        if(!mBlockSize) {
            if (mSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) break;
            in >> mBlockSize;
        }

        if(mSocket->bytesAvailable() < mBlockSize) break;

        qDebug() << "Package was recieved!";
        qDebug() << "Block size: " << mBlockSize;

        if(Table::INVALID_ID == mUser.id()) {
            QString authStr;
            in >> authStr;
            qDebug() << "Recieved account data: " << authStr;
        }

        mBlockSize = 0;
    }
}
```

And on the client side:

```
void Client::onConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Connected!";
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    //Reserve 2 bytes
    out << (quint16)0 << mEmail << "|" << mPassword;
    //Back to the beginning
    out.device()->seek(0);
    //Write a block size
    out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    mSocket->write(block);
}
```

Comment: It would help to edit the question to add any specific error messages or stack traces you are seeing.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and see where exactly it crashes

Comment: Malloc... something with `in` variable. Just it output not every time as I understood